# On click , Click another Button not working. The target button is a data-target type button

Tags: javascript, ajax

Hello Folks both my buttons work when used individually, but when I use button A to click button B using Java script it does not work.  I know button A works becuase the alert I added to the script pops up.  But it won't invoke button B.  I have tried it using classes and ID. Help Appriciated.

```
//Button A
<a class="send-btn"> <?php echo $buttontext?> </a>

//Button B
<a id="open-modal" class="openmodal-btn" data-toggle="modal"  data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#modal">
 


// I have tried adding these in the js Script during testing.
$("#openmodal-btn").click();
$('.openmodal-btn').click();


<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
$('.send-btn').click(function(event){ 
$('.openmodal-btn').trigger('click');

});
});

</script>
```

Comment: Your code works .check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Swati911/mkgf41rq/) fiddle.

Comment: Thanks Swati, I ran your code and it works. In the example I noticed that  your button label  name is Send Modal but the button I am using in your example still has "SEND".   So I am not sure if thats whats invoking the button B?

Comment: No i have just use demo data there because you have `<?php echo $buttontext?>` so i have added random text . Also , that doesn't have any relation with click event .

Comment: Okay thanks Swati  the issue must be becuase it is (and modal)are in  a SQL while statement loop.

Comment: I will do some testing

Comment: I found the issue thanks Swati. I have always   had this link above all my scripts as soon as I removed it it all works!! "
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>"

Answer (score 0):

Removing this link below which stood above all my Scripts at the bottom of the page  resolved this issue as I had the same link duplicated in the page header.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And thanks to Swati for helping with troubleshooting!